# MatplotLib - Displaying Data under Graph / Plot

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, bar-chart

My graph has Xticks Yticks , Xlabels , Ylabels .

```
My Code 



 firmwareList = self.firmware # Gets the list of all firmwares , this is a list
```

I need to put this firmware data under each bar .

Basically i need to put the build version below the X axis for each bar.

```
Example  |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |____________________
         0.0.1   0.0.2    0.0.3
```

I have already used Xticks, Xlabels .

How do i put the data on the x axis. its a list.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding things, but based on your comments to @ars, simply putting appending `\n` and the firmware version to your xticklabels should do what you want... (I'm posting this as an answer so that I can include an example image)  E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(range(3), [10,20,30], align='center')
plt.xticks(range(3), ['frogs\n1.0.0', 'turtles\n1.0.1', 'cheetas\n2.0.0'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Text beneath labels]

Is that what you wanted, or are you needing something more complex?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want . the only this is the frogs , turtles are one list and 1.0.0 , 2.0.0 are another list . how do i make join the data from the two lists and leave a space.

Comment: +1 much simpler than transformation method.  :)  @John:  ['%s\n%s' % (a, b) for a, b in zip(['firm 1', 'firm 2'], ['0.1', '0.2'])]

Comment: Hi My two lists : ['DHCP', 'STATIC', 'DHCP', 'STATIC', 'PPPOE', 'DHCP']
['1.0.00_build_01', '1.0.00_build_03', '1.0.00_build_05']  your code : ['%s\n%s' % (a, b) for a, b in zip(protocolNames, firmwareList)] some numbers are getting displayed on the graph. I dont see them getting displayed : (

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the second argument to [`xticks`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) function:

```
xticks(arange(3), ('firmware 1', 'firmware 2', 'firmware 3'))
```

*Update*:  I think the following first example named "*tick label like annotations*" on the [Matplotlib Transformations](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Transformations) page of the SciPy cookbook covers the general method you're after.

Note that there was an API change, so line 4 should be:

```
blend = M.transforms.blended_transform_factory
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but I have already displayed the ticks using xticks function. I want to display more data under the Xticks.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean?  Looking at the ASCII chart in your question, it seems you can replace `('firemware 1', ..` in my answer with `('0.0.1', '0.0.2', ..` in your chart and you should be all set, no?

Comment: OK i will expand in detail My existing code already has an xticks function self.ax.set_xticklabels( protocolNames) where protocolNames = [DHCP , static , PPOE , etc] .I want to display the firmware version under these existing values. My List of firmware values are a list firmwareList = [Build1 , Build 2, Build3 ]
Basically i will be displaying the protocol names and under the protocol names the firmware version.

Comment: @John: OK, I think I get it.  See the link I posted in the updated answer.